# How to use Pdflatex with Pandoc?

Tags: cygwin, pandoc, pdflatex

I'm using Pandoc to convert my markdown files to different formats including `html` and `docx`. With PDF though, I get the message `pdflatex not found` even though it was installed and I can even call it directly from Cygwin.

Why is Pandoc not detecting Pdflatex and what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you install pandoc?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this - I suspect you installed the windows version of Pandoc.  In cygwin, if you run `which pandoc` do you get something like `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Pandoc/pandoc`?

If so, it appears that version expects windows-style paths (e.g. C:\path\to\pdflatex), but cygwin is probably giving it something like "/path/to/pdflatex".

You might find success building pandoc from source, inside your cygwin environment.

Comment: I was just looking at this and I think I see what is throwing pandoc. On Cygwin, pdflatex is a symlink to pdftex.exe. If you specify the full path using the --latex-engine switch, it errors out that "pandoc.exe: latex-engine must be pdflatex, lualatex, or xelatex."

Answer (score 1):

@Wiscocrew's answer is on the right path, but, unfortunately, it is a little more complicated than that.

Pandoc permits you to pass the full path to `pdflatex` with the `--latex-engine` switch (c.f. http://pandoc.org/README.html#options-affecting-specific-writers), but if you just do something like

```
--latex-engine=`cygpath -w /usr/bin/pdflatex`
```

Pandoc gives a different error: `pandoc.exe: latex-engine must be pdflatex, lualatex, or xelatex.`. The reason for this error is that Cygwin's pdflatex is an symlink:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/pdflatex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser Domain Users 10 Mar 14 11:52 /usr/bin/pdflatex -> pdftex.exe
```

My work around was to copy `/usr/bin/pdftex.exe` to `/usr/local/bin/pdflatex.exe` and pass it to Pandoc like so:

```
pandoc Foo.md -o Foo.pdf --latex-engine='C:\\cygwin64\\usr\\local\\bin\\pdflatex.exe' -t latex -s
```

Comment: I guess to make this work seamlessly we would need pandoc compiled for cygwin in the first place.

Comment: I would think so, but each time I've tried to build GHC on Cygwin, I decided that life was just too short for that exercise.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally PDF from Markdown under Cygwin! You saved the day.